# If a Vampire Lord turns a creature with 5+ HD, does it become a normal Vampire or a Vampire Slave?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, hit-dice

In D&D 3.5, a Vampire Lord creates vampire slaves, rather than vampire spawn. However, when a creature with 5+ HD is turned, it becomes a vampire, not a vampire spawn.

Does this mean that if a Vampire Lord turns a 5+ HD creature, it's a normal vampire under the same rules of control, or is it also a vampire slave?

And on another note, are these vampire slaves statted as regular vampires/vampire spawn when created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vampire creates either vampire spawn slaves, or vampire slaves. That is, slaves that are vampire spawn or slaves that are vampires. The vampire lord is the same, except it always creates slaves that are vampires, not slaves that are vampire spawn.

However, if you are a player, the vampire lord has no listed level adjustment; you would have to ask your DM about what LA it’s supposed to have. It does not appear that vampire lords were intended to be playable, and my guess would be that the most appropriate ruling would be “LA: —,” that is, the template is not playable.